# UI doesn' t update in qt app

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, signals-slots, qtablewidget

In the code above uitablewidget does not update using signal and slot.
It seems as if (ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,newItemx);) doesn't work.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to update my qtablewidget from my class B?

```
Class_A::Class_A(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Class_A)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

}

Class_A::~Class_A()
{
delete ui;
}


void Class_A::change_TableWidget(double x,double y) // this is the    public slot
{
QTableWidgetItem *newItemx = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(x));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,newItemx);
QTableWidgetItem *newItemy = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(y));
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,newItemy);
}




Class_B::Class_B(QWidget *parent) :
 QGLWidget(parent)
{
Class_A *t=new Class_A;
connect(this,SIGNAL(mySignal(double,double)),t,SLOT(change_TableWidget(double,double)));
}


void Class_B::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
double x = event->x();
double y = event->y();
emit mySignal(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Check this out : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4559-adding-items-in-qtablewidget

Comment: Is change_TableWidget called at all? You should check this first.

Comment: The command ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,newItemx); works fine in the constructor of the class, and i have also ckecked that my function (change_TableWidget(double x,double y)) is called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a SLOT(change_TableWidget(double,double)) - yours takes 3 doubles, not two.

You should check that connect() returned true. I like to write
if (!connect(....)) Q_ASSERT(false);

or if (!connect(....)) Q_ASSERT(!"connect");

Also, connect prints out messages to the debug output when it fails to match the signals and slots. You should look for that output.

(Or use the new Qt 5 connect(), which is all checked at compile time.)

Comment: Hamish, you were right about that it was my mistake, but my problem still remains, and i have also ckecked that my function (change_TableWidget(double x,double y)) is called and even though it's entered variables don't show up in tablewidget!

Comment: You are always setting the item in the top left corner, row 0, column 0. And you set it twice in a row. You aren't setting the item actually referred to by the x and y co-ordinates, if that was your intention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem is that neither x , nor y is showing up to the cell of my tablewidget, what must i do so that the cell can take and show any value at all anyway?